# Given a random variable R, find its characteristic function

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $R$ be a random variable such that his density function is $f_R(r)=r\cdot e^{-r}\cdot u(r)$ for $r\geq 0$. Find $R$'s characteristic function $\Phi(\omega)$.

I got no idea where to start, any ideas?

P.S there is a clue: note that the integrand is "almost" a derivative by $\omega$.

So what I tried is by definition $\Phi_R(\omega)=E[e^{i\omega R}]=\int_0^\infty r^2\cdot e^{-r}\cdot e^{i\omega r}\cdot u(r)dr$

Because $u$ isn't given, I don't know how am I supposed to do that. I didn't entirely understand the clue. Is it that $\frac{d}{d\omega}r^2\cdot e^{-r}\cdot e^{i\omega r}\cdot u(r)$ is "almost" $r^2\cdot e^{-r}\cdot e^{i\omega r}\cdot u(r)$?

I'd be happy for some help if anyone got any ideas.

Comment: You could try starting with the definition of the characteristic function...

Comment: i tried but got stuck, Nothing fits into the integral

Comment: What is the function $u$? Can you edit your post to include the integral you mention, and explain where you got stuck?

Comment: $u$ isn't given. It's one of the problems I had

Comment: Why do you have $r^2$ in the integrand?

Comment: Is it possible that $u$ is the Heaviside function?  I've seen this notation in some books.